# Convert Javascript to Code Behind in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to convert the following JavaScript into the code behind (C#) of an ASP.NET page.
This is the JavaScript:

```
 function DisableButton() {
        document.getElementById("<%=Submit.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
    }
   window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;
```

I am trying to build a Client Script as follows (but get error message, see after the code):

```
StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();

cstext.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function DisableButton() {");
// I get error on the following line that semi-colon is missing
cstext.Append("document.getElementById("<%=Submit.ClientID %>").disabled = true; }";
cstext.Append("window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;");
cstext.Append("</script>");
```

I get error that the semi-colon is missing. What do I need to change in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
cstext.Append("document.getElementById("<%=Submit.ClientID %>").disabled = true; }";
```

should be

```
cstext.Append("document.getElementById('" + Submit.ClientID + "').disabled = true; }");
```

Comment: It would be nice to understand why changing the syntax from  ClientID inside the percent sign and brackets to a sting works. I just don't get it; but it works.

Comment: Percent sign is used when writing in the page code to indicate that some C# code should be executed when rendering the page. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.100).aspx